# How to avoid Inno to remember DefaultGroupName chosen during the previous install

Tags: inno-setup

I have some problem with Inno Setup.
I have two .exe with the same GUID (the second are the updated first).
I'm trying to create new [Icon] into second :

```
DefaultGroupName = XXXX_2

[Icons]    
Name: "{group}\XXXX"; Filename: "{drive:{app}}\XXXX\XXXX.exe";  WorkingDir:"{drive:{app}}\XXXX"; IconFileName: "{drive:{app}}\XXXX\XXXX.ico"
```

but during the installation, the Select Start Menu Folder field are the same than the first .exe ( XXXX_1 ). I know that it's about the DefaultGroupName.
By default Inno will remember the paths chosen during the previous install and default to those, even if you change your script.

And, I would know how to avoid this behaviour ?

To resolve this problem, I have to change the GUID. But I dont want two entries for one software into add/remove. And I think this is a little dirty solution.

Someone knows about that ?
Thanks you !

Comment: Be vary careful that the group is the only thing you make exclude. If you also tell it not to use the previous installation directly it can orphan off the main install. You amy also want to set `UpdateUninstallLogAppName` to false if the AppName is different. Also, whay are you discarding the app dir and using the root of the drive?

Comment: Thank you. With your comment I notified that I have now a new problem about the uninstaller.

Comment: You should be very careful when using this.  If the user customises the group name during a prior install they typically expect their choice to be remembered the next time, and may not actually read it.  As a result, they will end up with two icons in different folders.  While both of them will still get cleaned up on uninstall (as long as the app dir doesn't change, at least), this isn't particularly user friendly.

Comment: Exactly. Now the problem is that I have only one entry for the software in add/remove interface, but previous versions still installed with their own folders. I think we will try to find a new way of design ... Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [UsePreviousGroup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_usepreviousgroup).

```
[Setup]
UsePreviousGroup=no
```